# Listen buttonUp event in spark Button

Tags: apache-flex, button, flex4, flex-spark

There is event in spark Button - buttonDown. But how to determine the button up event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no buttonUp event. Although you can always rely on keyUp(for Keyboard) and mouseUp(for mouse).

Comment: I use FlexEvent buttonDown, to detect down state of button. And MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, Event.MOUSE_LEAVE to detect up state

Answer (score 0):

The click event is a combination of mouseDown and mouseUp.  That's the one I usually listen to.